# Three dimentional scatter plot doesn't work in spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, scatter-plot

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to create a 3D scatter plot. The spyder generates the 3D axis object but it is empty:

[image]

The code I found on the internet should create a 3D scatterplot of pixel colors of an image. The code also contained a variable `pixel_colors` but I did not know what it was, so I deleted it from the code:

```
 axis .scatter(h.flatten(), s.flatten(), v.flatten(), facecolors=pixel_colores, marker=".")
```

I used the code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
syd = cv2.imread('E:/Sydney-Opera-House.jpg')
hsv_syd = cv2.cvtColor(syd, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_syd)
fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")
axis .scatter(h.flatten(), s.flatten(), v.flatten(), marker=".")
axis .set_xlabel("Hue")
axis .set_ylabel("Saturation")
axis .set_zlabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

I checked that the plotted variables `s`, `h`, and `v` contain data, but nothing is shown in the graph.

[Here is the spyder console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYzEt.png)

I tried other codes from the net, none of them worked. But 2D plots are generated as expected. Restarting the spyder kernel did not solve the problem. What could be the problem?

Comment: Would you mind pasting the code here and showing what error are you getting?

Comment: there is not any error, just there is nothing to show

Comment: The axis was created correctly, but the dots in the scatterplot doesn't show.
I checked several codes copied from the webpages but all of them didn't show lines and dots

Comment: s,h,v contain data

Comment: yes I restart the kernel and close and open the Spyder. but there is not any colored dots. I checked the stackoverflow several times and used other simple codes to make a 3d plot. I was not succeed.
In all codes the `plot.show()` didn't worked

Comment: Yes it is ok for 2d plots

Comment: I summarized the problem and included the information from your comments. I suggest changing the code to the simplest form that reproduces the problem: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` `fig = plt.figure()` `axis = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")` `axis.plot([1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 1])` `plt.show()` This should generate a line in a 3D space but it does not in your case. Everything else is just a distraction from your problem. Sounds like a spyder-specific configuration problem. I do not know anything about spyder, so cannot be of any help.

Comment: Thank you.


Finally after a day I found what is the problem.
according to https://geo-python.github.io/2017/lessons/L7/matplotlib.html
We should:
In the Preferences window, click on IPython console on the left side of the window, then on the Graphics tab.
Under Graphics backend, select Automatic for the backend.
Restart Spyder.